# Notepad++ match multiple occurrences of a string in multiple lines (and replace)

Tags: replace, notepad++

I want to match those substrings which have the `$` character in below lines.

They all should be replaced with `TEST`. They are not necessarily between quotations (`""`) or `$` and are not necessarily at the beginning of those substrings.

I guess those which are not between "" could be delimited by `=`, `;`,or `,`

What could be the simplest regex to achieve this?

```
CACCALLPLC: CALLPLCNAME="${EPolicyCacName}", MCB=$BANDWIDTH;
CACPLCSET: CACPLCSETNAME="${BandPolicyName}",ACPLCSETMODE=SHARE,ALLPLCNAME="${EPolicyCacName}";
SIPAN: ANNAME="E_$BackupCorporateName", LETYPE=P-CSCF, ADDRNAME="$ADDRNAME";
```

Expected result:

```
CACCALLPLC: CALLPLCNAME="TEST", MCB=TEST;
CACPLCSET: CACPLCSETNAME="TEST",ACPLCSETMODE=SHARE,ALLPLCNAME="TEST";
SIPAN: ANNAME="TEST", LETYPE=P-CSCF, ADDRNAME="TEST";
```

Comment: Please post your sample of expected output along with your efforts in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: You could probably do something in the lines of `[^"=]*?\$[^;",]*`, this will try to do that. [link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Rx8EoS/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something in the lines of this `[^"=]*\$[^;",]*`

This will try to look for a match, through a few steps.

- `[^"=]*` - Looks for 0 to unlimited characters not `"` or `=`
- `\$` - Looks for the character `$`
- `[^;",]*` - Looks for 0 to unlimited characters not `;`, `,` or `"`

This will try to look for a `$` in the middle of some delimiters. You can then replace the matches with `TEST`

Example of this on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Rx8EoS/2)

Answer (score 0):

This regex works (using the JavaScript regex engine), to capture the correct text, then you just need to replace the matches text with your test (`TEST`)

```
\w*\$\{?\w+\}?
```

Edited: It does now match `ANNAME="E_$BackupCorporateName",` correctly. With the benefit of being shorter, and easier to ready, albeit not handling for non-word characters before a `$` inside the match. For robustness, @Nils' answer is better.

Comment: No this fails to match `ANNAME="E_$BackupCorporateName", correctly.`